# Excluir várias linhas do SQL Server que têm o mesmo trecho de texto?

Tags: sql, servidor

Para testar o meu formulários, executei vários preenchimentos com a palavra "teste" nos campos. Agora eu queria limpar o BD, porém estou tendo dificuldades para excluir várias linhas com o mesmo trecho de texto "teste"

Estou aplicando o seguinte comando, mas nenhuma linha é afetada.

```
Delete FROM [DB_ControleDemandas].[dbo].[formulario] where Datas = '%Teste%'
```

Comment: A sintaxe correta para o seu where seria: where Datas like '%Teste%'

Comment: Sabia que era simples, rs. Obrigado!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usando o comando da forma descrita está a tentar apagar todas as linhas com o texto `%Teste%`. O que pretende aqui é apagar todas as linhas que contenha o texto *'Teste'*, independentemente de onde esteja colocado. O comando a usar será o `LIKE`, da seguinte forma:

```
DELETE FROM [DB_ControleDemandas].[dbo].[formulario] WHERE Datas LIKE '%Teste%'
```

Comment: Sabia que era simples, rs. Obrigado!

Comment: @DanielGomes, vale a pena marcar a resposta como aceita, se resolveu o problema ;) ([por que aceitar uma resposta](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1078/como-e-por-que-aceitar-uma-resposta))